# Ruby on Rails [has_one]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

So I'm pretty new to Rails; I have an assignment I'm trying to finish for my coursework and I'm stuck. I already have Topics and Posts for a reddit clone that the assignment is on. But now I'm supposed to add one summary for each post and after diving into that for awhile, I am stuck.

Here are the assignment requirements:

- Create a Summary model which references posts.
- Modify Post so that it has_one summary.
- Create the necessary routes to create and show post summaries.
- Create Summary views to create and show post summaries.

---

The error I'm hitting when I try to follow a 'Summary' link I've created to sit next to a post title:

### ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Topics#show

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"summaries", :id=>nil, :post_id=>nil, :topic_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id, :post_id]`

---

It's pointing me to the Topics#show method which looks like this:

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @topic.posts
  authorize @topic
end
```

---

And my SummariesController looks like this:

```
class SummariesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = @topic.posts
    @summary = Summary.new
    authorize @summary
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = @topic.posts
    @summary = Summary.new(params.require(:summary).permit(:description))
    authorize @summary
    if @summary.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your post summary was saved"
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else 
      flash[:error] = "Sorry. There was an error saving your summary. Please try again"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @summary = Summary.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    authorize @summary 
  end
end
```

---

And here are my models:

#### Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_one :summary
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic

  default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

#### Topic:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

#### Summary:

```
class Summary < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

---

Lastly here is my routes file and the html.erb link:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index] do
      resources :summaries, except: [:index, :edit]
    end
  end

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'

end
```

html.erb summary Link:

```
<small>
  <%= link_to "Summary", topic_post_summary_path(@topic, @post, @summary)%>
</small>
```

---

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Lets see your summary link and your routes.

Comment: @fatfrog Added routes and summary link which is inside of the topics#show view

Comment: Looks like @ post, @ summary are not defined in your show action?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the resources nested?  Also, in your `Topic` model, you might want `has_many :summaries, :through => :post`.

Comment: @steveklein They had me do it for demonstration purposes

Comment: I agree with @fatfrog. From what you have provided, my impression is that the failing link is referencing two variables (`@post` and `@summary`) that were not defined. It might depend on the context of the link, though (for example, perhaps you defined them somewhere in `show.html.erb` by iterating over `@posts`), so it is difficult to say for certain without seeing a little more of `show.html.erb`.